# How to use ViewPager, or something else, to just scroll through text?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Everything I have seen is overkill. I am simply looking for a way to have some part of my app scroll through several text snippets when swiping left/right. Imagine an image gallery that you scroll through, but just a line of text for each instead of an image. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at my other posts for more detailed answer. The explanation is very simple in my **other posts**.

[How to properly use fragments with ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042388/how-to-properly-use-fragments-with-viewpager/21801145#21801145)

[Multiple ViewPagers in on Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270144/multiple-viewpagers-in-on-activity/23276994#23276994)

[How to swipe xml layouts using ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059545/how-to-swipe-xml-layouts-using-viewpager/22084847#22084847)

These are few examples you can find helpful. Hope this helps.. :)

**If still having some issues with those answers, take a look at this simple example:**

Just follow simple steps here:

**Step 1: Create layout for your view pager:(activity_main.xml)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="#333333">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Step 2: Create another layout to hold your textview items: (items.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#94999F"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 3:** In you Main Activity create a class for your adapter or you can create a separate class for your adapter. This is just an adapter inside the same class. Here's the full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    String[] items = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
    ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        /*for (String s : items) {

            mArrayList.add(s);

        }*/

            for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){

        mArrayList.add("Item " + i);

    }

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, mArrayList);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    /*Here's the adapter*/
    private class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Context context;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> newsomeList) {

            super();
            this.context = context;
            this.someList = newsomeList;

        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.finishUpdate(container);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return someList.size();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View collection, Object object) {

            return collection == ((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            // Inflating layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // Setting view you want to display as a row element
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);

            TextView itemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
            // Getting reference for text view and inflate the view for Answers

            try {

                itemText.setText(someList.get(position));

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            return view;

        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);

        }

    }

}
```

And that's you need .. :)

Hope this will help you.. Its a very simple example for what you need.. Good Luck .. :)

Comment: Your array list will not be the same as mine but you will be having more items/list according to your needs. If any questions, let me know.

Comment: Glad I was able to help .. Good Luck ..:)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this: [Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HorizontalScrollView`. An example is [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/). Instead of Buttons, you can use `TextView` to serve you puroise.

Or else you can use `ViewPager` also. Already others have given you tutorial just follow that. But I think, to serve your purpose `HorizontalScrollView` is needed.